# Mule: Multiple flows in the same session

Tags: java, web-services, session, esb, mule

I have an Mule application whose purpose is to send emails. The application performs 2 steps:

1) In the first flow, it accepts requests on an endpoint and writes it to a vm queue.

2) In the second flow, the message in the vm queue is sent as HTTPPost to a webservice component, which would send the email .

So, far I have not done anything to 'session' in my mule_config.xml. Thus AFAIK, both the flows will be under the same session.

Now, is it a good practice to have multiple flows under the same session, or do I need to have a different session for each flow (if that is possible)? What are the pros/cons of the above approach in which both the flows run under the same session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First bear in mind that a session in Mule is not like a session in a web container: it is simply a particular message properties scope that can span multiple flows.

Consider the following:

```
<flow name="SessionDemo">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="test.in" />
    <set-session-variable variableName="mySessionVar"
        value="myValue" />
    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="next.in" />
</flow>
<flow name="SessionPropagationDemo">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="next.in" />
    <logger message="#[sessionVars.mySessionVar]"/>
</flow>
```

If you run this example, you'll see that the `mySessionVar` session-scoped message property (aka session variable) has been propagated via the VM queue to the next flow.

If you need to carry message properties across multiple flows, using session variables will make your life easier otherwise you will have to manually copy properties from the inbound to the outbound scope each time your "hopping" to the next flow via a transport (this doesn't apply to `flow-ref` "hops").